# how can I get row number via php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
id  state
1     1
2     0
5     1
4     0
7     1
```

I want first remove all `state=0` form my result. and then return row number of target record.

for example for `id='7'` it must return me `3`

how can I do it with mysqli/php?

this is false but something like this:

```
  function getLogs($itime = 0,$count = null)
    {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        $sql = "SELECT num_rows() FROM Content Where id='22' and  $state=0 ORDER BY id ASC";
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($conn->query($sql), MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $this->disconnectDB($conn);
        return num_rows();
    }
```

Comment: Why did you use `$state=0` in the SQL if you are looking for places where `$state` is not `0`?

Comment: I have a list of articls in my DB. I publish them in a blog list with several pages. I want dynamically link to articls url in blog view.some articls are deactive ($state = 0)... I must remove deactive article fist...I hope u underestand me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably simpler and you can replace 22 with a variable.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Content WHERE id <= 22 AND state != 0
```

In your example you put 22 in quotes, but your id isn't a string is it?  Plus in addition to the comment above about `$state = 0`, it should be `state` not `$state`